# How to account for changes in b-tree in a second b-tree of indices and pointers?

Tags: c++, database, b-tree

I am working on a B-tree project for a class I am taking and am stuck on an issue. I have already written code to create the B-tree, as well as insert, delete, traverse, and search functions. I now have to create another tree of indices and pointers to the first tree.

**What I am unable to figure out is how can I efficiently account for changes in the first tree in the second tree of pointers?**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


struct student {
    int ID;         //0
    string name;    //1

    //friend istream& operator >>(istream& s, student& u) {
        // read in a user from disk
    //}

};

template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
class BTreeNode
{
    Record* keys;  // An array of keys
    BTreeNode** C; // An array of child pointers
    int n;     // Current number of keys
    bool leaf; // Is true when node is leaf. Otherwise false

public:
    BTreeNode(bool _leaf);
    void traverse();
    BTreeNode* search(const PrimaryKeyType& k);

    int findKey(const PrimaryKeyType& k);

    void insertNonFull(const Record& k);
    void splitChild(int i, BTreeNode* y);

    void remove(const Record& k);
    void removeFromLeaf(int idx);
    void removeFromNonLeaf(int idx);
    const Record& getPred(int idx);
    const Record& getSucc(int idx);
    void fill(int idx);
    void borrowFromPrev(int idx);
    void borrowFromNext(int idx);
    void merge(int idx);


    template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
    friend class BTree;     //maybe move inside BTree
};

constexpr uint32_t blocksize = 1024;        //TODO: confirm block size and change formula bc we may have assumed t was max size instead of min
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
class BTree
{
    BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>* root;

public:
    constexpr static uint32_t rec_per_block = blocksize / sizeof(Record);
    void remove(const Record& k);
    void insert(const Record& k);
    BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>* search(PrimaryKeyType k) {
        return root->search(k);
    }

    BTree() : root(new BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>(true)) { //1k/size of student instead of t 

    }

    void traverse() {
        root->traverse();
    }

};

template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::BTreeNode(bool leaf) :leaf(leaf), n(0) {
    keys = new Record[2 * BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1];
    C = new BTreeNode * [2 * BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block];

}

template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
int BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::findKey(const PrimaryKeyType& k)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while(idx < n && keys[idx].*PrimaryKey < k)
        ++idx;
    return idx;
}

template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::remove(const Record& k)
{
    int idx = findKey(k.*PrimaryKey);

    if(idx < n && keys[idx].*PrimaryKey == k.*PrimaryKey) {
        if(leaf)
            removeFromLeaf(idx);
        else
            removeFromNonLeaf(idx);
    } else {
        if(leaf) {
            cout << "The key does not exist in the tree\n";
            return;
        }

        bool flag = ((idx == n) ? true : false);

        if(C[idx]->n < BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block)
            fill(idx);
        if(flag && idx > n)
            C[idx - 1]->remove(k);
        else
            C[idx]->remove(k);
    }
    return;
}

template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::removeFromLeaf(int idx) {
    for(int i = idx + 1; i < n; ++i)
        keys[i - 1] = keys[i];
    n--;
    return;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::removeFromNonLeaf(int idx) {
    const Record& k = keys[idx];
    if(C[idx]->n >= BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block) {
        const Record& pred = getPred(idx);
        keys[idx] = pred;
        C[idx]->remove(pred);
    }

    else if(C[idx + 1]->n >= BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block) {
        const Record& succ = getSucc(idx);
        keys[idx] = succ;
        C[idx + 1]->remove(succ);
    }

    else {
        merge(idx);
        C[idx]->remove(k);
    }
    return;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
const Record& BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::getPred(int idx) {
    BTreeNode* cur = C[idx];
    while(!cur->leaf)
        cur = cur->C[cur->n];

    return cur->keys[cur->n - 1];
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
const Record& BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::getSucc(int idx) {

    BTreeNode* cur = C[idx + 1];
    while(!cur->leaf)
        cur = cur->C[0];

    return cur->keys[0];
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::fill(int idx) {

    if(idx != 0 && C[idx - 1]->n >= BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block)
        borrowFromPrev(idx);

    else if(idx != n && C[idx + 1]->n >= BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block)
        borrowFromNext(idx);

    else {
        if(idx != n)
            merge(idx);
        else
            merge(idx - 1);
    }
    return;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::borrowFromPrev(int idx) {
    BTreeNode* child = C[idx];
    BTreeNode* sibling = C[idx - 1];

    for(int i = child->n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        child->keys[i + 1] = child->keys[i];

    if(!child->leaf) {
        for(int i = child->n; i >= 0; --i)
            child->C[i + 1] = child->C[i];
    }

    child->keys[0] = keys[idx - 1];

    if(!child->leaf)
        child->C[0] = sibling->C[sibling->n];

    keys[idx - 1] = sibling->keys[sibling->n - 1];

    child->n += 1;
    sibling->n -= 1;

    return;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::borrowFromNext(int idx) {
    BTreeNode* child = C[idx];
    BTreeNode* sibling = C[idx + 1];

    child->keys[(child->n)] = keys[idx];

    if(!(child->leaf))
        child->C[(child->n) + 1] = sibling->C[0];

    keys[idx] = sibling->keys[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < sibling->n; ++i)
        sibling->keys[i - 1] = sibling->keys[i];

    if(!sibling->leaf) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= sibling->n; ++i)
            sibling->C[i - 1] = sibling->C[i];
    }

    child->n += 1;
    sibling->n -= 1;
    return;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::merge(int idx) {
    BTreeNode* child = C[idx];
    BTreeNode* sibling = C[idx + 1];

    child->keys[BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1] = keys[idx];
    for(int i = 0; i < sibling->n; ++i)
        child->keys[i + BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block] = sibling->keys[i];

    if(!child->leaf) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= sibling->n; ++i)
            child->C[i + BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block] = sibling->C[i];
    }

    for(int i = idx + 1; i < n; ++i)
        keys[i - 1] = keys[i];

    for(int i = idx + 2; i <= n; ++i)
        C[i - 1] = C[i];

    child->n += sibling->n + 1;
    n--;
    delete(sibling);
    return;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::insert(const Record& k) {

    if(root->n == 0) {

        root->keys[0] = k;
        root->n = 1;
    } else {
        if(root->n == 2 * rec_per_block - 1) {
            BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>* s = new BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>(false);
            s->C[0] = root;
            s->splitChild(0, root);

            int i = 0;
            if(s->keys[0].*PrimaryKey < k.*PrimaryKey)
                i++;
            s->C[i]->insertNonFull(k);
            root = s;
        } else
            root->insertNonFull(k);
    }
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::insertNonFull(const Record& k) {

    int i = n - 1;
    if(leaf == true) {
        while(i >= 0 && keys[i].*PrimaryKey > k.*PrimaryKey) {
            keys[i + 1] = keys[i];
            i--;
        }

        keys[i + 1] = k;
        n = n + 1;
    } else {
        while(i >= 0 && keys[i].*PrimaryKey > k.*PrimaryKey)
            i--;

        if(C[i + 1]->n == 2 * BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1) {
            splitChild(i + 1, C[i + 1]);

            if(keys[i + 1].*PrimaryKey < k.*PrimaryKey)
                i++;
        }
        C[i + 1]->insertNonFull(k);
    }
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::splitChild(int i, BTreeNode* y) {
    BTreeNode* z = new BTreeNode(y->leaf);
    z->n = BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1;

    for(int j = 0; j < BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1; j++)
        z->keys[j] = y->keys[j + BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block];

    if(y->leaf == false) {
        for(int j = 0; j < BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block; j++)
            z->C[j] = y->C[j + BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block];
    }
    y->n = BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1;

    for(int j = n; j >= i + 1; j--)
        C[j + 1] = C[j];

    C[i + 1] = z;

    for(int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--)
        keys[j + 1] = keys[j];

    keys[i] = y->keys[BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::rec_per_block - 1];
    n = n + 1;
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::traverse() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(leaf == false)
            C[i]->traverse();
        cout << " (" << keys[i].ID << "," << keys[i].name << ")";
    }

    if(leaf == false)
        C[i]->traverse();
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>* BTreeNode<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::search(const PrimaryKeyType& k) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n && k > keys[i].*PrimaryKey)
        i++;

    if(keys[i].*PrimaryKey == k)
        return this;

    if(leaf == true)
        return NULL;

    return C[i]->search(k);
}
template<typename Record, typename PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKeyType Record::* PrimaryKey>
void BTree<Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>::remove(const Record& k) {       // TODO: possibly change to int k if that makes UI more efficient
    if(!root) {
        cout << "The tree is empty\n";
        return;
    }
    root->remove(k);

    if(root->n == 0) {
        BTreeNode <Record, PrimaryKeyType, PrimaryKey>* tmp = root;
        if(root->leaf)
            root->n = 0;
        else
            root = root->C[0];
        delete tmp;
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    //BTree<student, int, &student::ID> t;
    BTree<student, string, &student::name> t;

    t.insert({1, "Bob"});
    t.insert({3, "Steve"});
    t.insert({7, "Phil"});
    t.insert({10, "Zack"});
    t.insert({11, "Rick"});
    t.insert({13, "Mike"});
    t.insert({14, "Todd"});
    t.insert({15, "Will"});
    t.insert({18, "Jason"});
    t.insert({16, "Kevin"});
    t.insert({19, "Bill"});
    t.insert({24, "Anthony"});
    t.insert({25, "Kate"});
    t.insert({26, "Joe"});
    t.insert({21, "Alex"});
    t.insert({4, "Jen"});
    t.insert({5, "Matt"});
    t.insert({20, "Danny"});
    t.insert({22, "Jack"});
    t.insert({2, "Gill"});
    t.insert({17, "Evan"});
    t.insert({12, "Ian"});
    t.insert({6, "Chris"});

    cout << "Traversal of tree constructed is\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;

    t.remove({6, "Chris"});
    cout << "Traversal of tree after removing 6\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;

    t.remove({13, "Mike"});
    cout << "Traversal of tree after removing 13\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;

    t.remove({7, "Phil"});
    cout << "Traversal of tree after removing 7\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;

    t.remove({4, "Jen"});
    cout << "Traversal of tree after removing 4\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;

    t.remove({2, "Gill"});
    cout << "Traversal of tree after removing 2\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;

    t.remove({16, "Kevin"});
    cout << "Traversal of tree after removing 16\n";
    t.traverse();
    cout << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```